# How can I keep track of a user's session via JWT without storing it as a cookie or in localStorage/sessionStorage

Tags: java, reactjs, session, jwt

I've read in several places that it's not recommended to store a JWT in the browser, either in storage or as a cookie. Even if it was, for the current application I'm developing, we have the JWT stored on a java servlet, and are using a separate React app as a frontend.

I was thinking that I could just give each user an ID in a cookie and then check that their session is still valid by comparing the associated JWT.

Is there some recommended method for keeping track of a user's session with a JWT without actually sending the JWT to the user at any point? Every search I try results in a dozen articles telling me not to send JWT to the browser and store it there, but I wasn't planning to anyway. I'd like to avoid having to handle multiple methods of maintaining a user's session, and the JWT is something that isn't optional at this point.

Comment: You must have store the JWT tokens somewhere at client side. I prefer cookies with httpOnly option. Since session ends on tab close.

Comment: @AravindP I can't store some kind of ID on the client side and look up a JWT server-side for each request?

Comment: The only way you can store anything at all (in a practical sense)on the client side is through a cookie. There is no way you can keep track of users without sessions unless you made database requests with every url they requested which again isn't practical.

Comment: @JonathanLaliberte Right.... I'm not asking if there's a way to not store anything. I'm asking if there's a best practice for what to store _instead_ _of_ a JWT. I'm literally just thinking of a keeping map of id to jwt and wondering if there's a smarter way than that.